# Randomly allot values to the rows in python

Tags: python, pandas, random, randomized-algorithm

I have the following input table (y):

| parameter1 | parameter2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 23 |
| 3 | 66 |
| 4 | 98 |
| 5 | 90 |
| 6 | 14 |
| 7 | 7 |
| 8 | 56 |
| 9 | 1 |

I would like to randomly allot values from A1 to A9. The output table should look like the following:

| parameter1 | parameter2 | parameter3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | A5 |
| 2 | 23 | A2 |
| 3 | 66 | A4 |
| 4 | 98 | A8 |
| 5 | 90 | A3 |
| 6 | 14 | A7 |
| 7 | 7 | A1 |
| 8 | 56 | A9 |
| 9 | 1 | A6 |

```
n = 9

TGn = round(len(y)/n)
idx = set(y.index // TGn)

y = y.apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=1,random_state=1234)).reset_index(drop=True)
    
treatment_groups = [f"A{i}" for i in range(1, n+1)]
y['groupAfterRandomization'] = (y.index // TGn).map(dict(zip(idx, treatment_groups)))
```

I am unable to fill the first row value it prints as NaN. How do I tackle this problem?

Comment: Do you want to randomly alot values `A1` to `A9` based on the values from `parameter1`?

Comment: Your code looks fine after sorting with `parameter1` column.

Comment: Yes, based on parameter1

Answer (score 1):

#### `Series.sample`

We can use `sample` with `frac=1` to sample the values from the column `parameter1` then use `radd` to concatenate prefix `A` with the sampled values

```
df['parameter3'] = df['parameter1'].sample(frac=1).astype(str).radd('A').values
```

---

```
   parameter1  parameter2 parameter3
0           1          12         A2
1           2          23         A8
2           3          66         A1
3           4          98         A4
4           5          90         A9
5           6          14         A3
6           7           7         A6
7           8          56         A7
8           9           1         A5
```

Comment: Such an elegant solution. Just a quick question. I can't realize difference between `add` and `radd` method.

Comment: Thanks @ashkangh. To understand better lets consider an example, if you want to add `series` + `some value` then you would normally use `add` but if you want to add `some value` + `series` in such case you would use `radd`.

Comment: Ohhhh. Awesome!! And please rectify me if I'm wrong. Both methods also can be applied on `strings`, and if so, they concatenate both respective values. Right?

Comment: Both `add` and `radd` are the methods of  `pandas` `Series` object so you need `Series` object to use those methods.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! When I try to sample and concatenate with parameter1 I am not able to get parameter3 between A1-A9, rather it generates random number. How do I rectify that?

Comment: @MuSu18 Can you show the output that you are getting?